# What is the purpose of having one null value in unique key in sqlserver?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Many people have asked me that what is the advantage of one null value in unique key?

i am still unable to find the answer of that question

Comment: That's how the design was made. THe `UNIQUE` key means no duplicated values, so one `null` value is allowed. The `PRIMARY KEY` means no duplicated values but `null` value is not allowed.

Comment: the question is highly opinion base kind of but please someone give answer if knows .. i wish to get answer too ... i know one answer that it is by design but why design has been like this ??

Comment: @Dhaval There is nothing strange about this. The `unique` means no duplicated values - so, `null` is allowed. Why do you think a `unique` constrain should not allowed this?

Comment: @gotqn - Because `NULL = NULL` is not true. The SQL Standard dictates that unique constraints should allow multiple `NULL`.

Comment: @MartinSmith So, in this case, Miscrosoft does not follow the standard?

Comment: @gotqn - Yes. I think the design decision may predate the standard. Not sure about that though.

Comment: Even though SQL Server permits it, it isn't a good idea to put uniqueness constraints on nullable columns. You need to ensure that any columns subject to a uniqueness constraint are non-nullable. Over the years Microsoft have many times been asked to change their non-standard implementation of UNIQUE constraints but so far without success.

Answer (score 0):

The `unique` constrain means that no duplicated values are allowed. So, there is nothing wrong to have one `null` value.

FYI, after SQL Server 2008 and later you are allowed to create a `UNIQUE` index on a column that have multiple `NULL` values. This is done using a [Filtered Index](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372.aspx).

---

I just wanted to check what [@MartinSmith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73226/martin-smith) said about that `NULL = NULL` is not true and that the standard is not applied in SQL Server. So, after quick research I have found the following explanation proving his point:

> A unique key constraint does not imply the NOT NULL constraint in
>   practice. Because NULL is not an actual value (it represents the lack
>   of a value), when two rows are compared, and both rows have NULL in a
>   column, the column values are not considered to be equal. Thus, in
>   order for a unique key to uniquely identify each row in a table, NULL
>   values must not be used. According to the [SQL standard](http://www.sql.org/sql-database/postgresql/manual/ddl-constraints.html#AEN1832) and Relational
>   Model theory, a unique key (unique constraint) should accept NULL in
>   several rows/tuples — however not all RDBMS implement this feature
>   correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Although this question solicits speculation, there's one factual reason that a single `NULL` value makes sense from an implementors point of view: In the on-disk B-tree structure that SQL Server uses to implement an index, the `NULL` value is just like any other value. As long as the designers of SQL Server do not decide to create a special case for `NULL` values, this is the behavior you get **by default**.

And being able to index `NULL` values makes sense and is a useful feature. Counter-intuitively can use an index to seek on `NULL`: `WHERE IndexCol IS NULL`.